# JsonCpp heap object handling memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management, jsoncpp

With JsonCpp I want to serialize big objects with limited stack resources on an embedded device. All the examples I found are using stack objects which will be copied into each other (I guess). I want to reduce the copying the Json::Value objects all the time, but still using clustered code -- so that each object just needs to know how to serialize itself. I prepared a minimal example, which orientates to the described memory management from this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829726](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829726/7251286)

But in my example (in the end) there is still an not needed/wanted copy:

`(*p)["a"] = *a.toJson();  // value will be copied into new instance`

Can this be avoided somehow with JsonCpp?

```
    struct itoJson
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Json::Value> toJson();
    };

    struct A: itoJson
    {
        int i;
        std::shared_ptr<Json::Value> toJson()
        {
          std::shared_ptr<Json::Value> p = std::shared_ptr<Json::Value>(new Json::Value());
          (*p)["i"] = i;
          return p;
        }
    };

    struct B: itoJson
    {
        int x;
        A a;

        std::shared_ptr<Json::Value> toJson()
        {
          std::shared_ptr<Json::Value> p = std::shared_ptr<Json::Value>(new Json::Value());
          (*p)["x"] = x;
          (*p)["a"] = *a.toJson();  // value will be copied into new instance
          return p;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why are you using `shared_ptr`s? Return a `Json::Value` instead of a `std::shared_ptr<Json::Value>` and your code should become simpler and much faster.

Comment: Assuming by "stack objects" you mean objects with automatic storage duration, that's false; there is loads of dynamic allocation here, some in your own code.

Comment: @nwp I don't get your comment, because my question is exactly about not to the `Json::Value`
@BoundaryImposition usually I feel right when speaking about stack and heap objects, I think we mean the same, can you give me a hint were to look up the correct terms?

Comment: I think you forgot a word there, "not to *copy* the `Json::Value`". While it looks like code of the form `Type value = create_value();` makes a copy compilers are generally smart enough to optimize it away, even without optimization flags enabled, and let `create_value` create the value directly in its final place. You are inhibiting that optimization with the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @nwp ah ok, with the hint to relay on compiler optimization I understand, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonCpp does not support move semantics — this is [issue #223](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/223).

Until it does, you cannot entirely avoid copies.

However, if you make your code simple by getting rid of the needless dynamic allocation and smart pointers, you *may* get lucky and see your compiler optimising away some of it (via mechanisms like *return value optimisation*). But not all of it.